# which method should i use to fetch the phone number of a user which they provided during authentication

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
  ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, al);
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                list_user_id = ();
//                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                al.add(name);
//                    String phonenumber =
            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Check Your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

I want the phone number to be fetched in the list_user_id... for fetching current user phone number i can just use getPhoneNumber method but im not sure on how too fetch the Number of the user im chatting with

Comment: i want to fetch the phone number of the user im texting not the current user(me)

Comment: just add the phone number in the database and fetch it

Comment: the phone number is in the db in the users child.. from there how do i particularly fetch that user's number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String phonenumber=datas.child("phonenumber").getValue().toString();

   }
} 

  @Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
   }
});
```

Since you want to get the phone number of the person you are chatting with, then logically you would click on that person's name to start the chat, then you can use the query:

```
ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(Nameyouclicked).addValueEventListener(...){..}
```

This way you would have the name, then you can get the userid or anything related to that user.

Comment: http://ibb.co/dhOCJx - My database is like this... so when i tried this above code its giving a nullointer exception in the line "string phonenumber = ......"

Comment: @CourtneyMiller okay instead of `string phonenumber-...` write this `String phonenumber=datas.getKey();`

Comment: wont it return the unique id?

Comment: @CourtneyMiller no it would return the phone number, try it, since the phonenumber is in your database like a parent node to the following nodes("Email","Name","Quote","Status")

Comment: Yeah works... tysm AGAIN... lol