# Retrieving my phone number from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[which method should i use to fetch the phone number of a user which they provided during authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48679560/which-method-should-i-use-to-fetch-the-phone-number-of-a-user-which-they-provide?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In the above link, Actually i got somewhat what i wanted. Actually in my database, i'm also storing data as shown in the last comment by @Courtney Miller (http://ibb.co/dhOCJx) . Suppose there are multiple entries in the database using phone number as key instead of just one as shown in the link. How can i retrieve my own phone number (i'm logged in) ? 
If there are multiple entries which are using the phone number as their key, then the solution in the above link will always return the last entry.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys within the same node. If you write data that has the same key as an existing key, it will be overwritten. So, if you use your phone number as a key, that node willl be yours. Using the uid as the key is the way to go for a /users node as they will always be unique. Please include your actual Firebase structure in questions as text please, no images or link. If the link you included breaks, it would make the question unclear.

Comment: I'm not having any duplicate keys in my database. And yes you are right, Using the uid as the key is the way to go for a /users node as they will always be unique. But if my strcture is like     `users`    `phonenumber`    `name: Gaurav`    `address: address_here` . In this case how can i retrieve my `phonenumber` if i'm logged in.

Comment: Ah - that's going to be an issue. Use the users *uid* as the key to their node. So when they log in their data can be directly accessed at *root/users/uid_x*. That will eliminate the need for a query. Most importantly, it's best practice to not use variable data as keys i.e. what if the users phone number changes? You would have to delete and re-create that node and *everywhere else in your structure* that accesses that node. uid's are static and therefore are an excellent choice for keys.

Comment: Yes i also thought about user changing their `phoneNumber` but the app that i developed is for my college and, practically, everyone has a permanent number, which they use for their work and related stuffs. So, using this fact, i am not allowing a user to change `phoneNumber`. So using the `phoneNumber` as key won't do any harm. Also, it makes my task easier at the backend database side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use the `userid` as key instead of the phone number. But if you want to use the phone number as key, then add the `userid` as a child under the phone number like this:

```
Users
  phonenumber
      name: Gaurav
      userid: id_here
      address: address_here
```

Then to get information of the logged in user, try the following:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userid=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
ref.orderByChild("userid").equalTo(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    String phone=datas.getKey();
  }
} 

 @Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
   }
 });
```

This `String phone=datas.getKey();` will retrieve the source location of this snapshot, which is the phone number in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struck in this problem for 3 days, i was trying to retrieve Current User phone Number and was getting null pointer error so i google for it and after reading so many articles i get to know that i was using phone number as parent node instead of user ID.
Always make your parent node User ID, as retrieving userID is more easy then phone number.

**Just use this**

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
```

**instead of this**

```
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber()
```